# SDL window hangs on mouse action within window

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, sdl

I am using the most recent build "ffmpeg-n6.1-60b9630-win64-nonfree" from https://github.com/AnimMouse/ffmpeg-autobuild on windows 10.0.19045. I have a command line I created to capture video from a decklink card and stream it to a stream service.

```
C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -format_code Hi59 -f decklink -channels 2 -i "DeckLink Duo (1)" -c:a aac -b:a 256k -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v high -rc:v cbr_ld_hq -level:v 4.2 -r:v 30 -g:v 120 -bf:v 3 -b:v 5500000 -maxrate 6000000 -bufsize 9000000 -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[out1][out2];[out2]scale=640:360[out_sdl]" -map "[out1]" -map 0:a -preset p6 -f flv rtmps://rtmp.boxcast.com/live/streamkey -map "[out_sdl]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_x 20 -window_y 30 -window_enable_quit 1 -f sdl "CRPC English"
```

The command works fine and a window pops up displaying just the video that I am sending to the stream service, the problem is that if I move any window on the desktop the SDL window freezes and becomes unresponsive, the encoding and stream continue but the SDL window never recovers.

I think this is a bug in the Libsdl used in the ffmpeg build but I thought I would ask here if anyone can reproduce my results.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. If you want you can replace this part

```
-pix_fmt yuv420p -window_x 20 -window_y 30 -window_enable_quit 1 -f sdl "CRPC English"
```

with this one

```
-f matroska - | ffplay - -vf scale=960:540 -left 20 -top 30
```

Comment: What does this mean? Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Yes in this way you can preview what you're recording without using sdl option